# Sending HEX with CuteCom

Tags: serial-port

I'm working a lot with CuteCom at the moment. But I could not yet find out how to send hex to the serial port. As an example I would like to send the character 0xFF. 
In the description on the internet it says, that CuteCom can do that. But how?

Comment: Can you show us the manual that says how? I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: No, I can not tell you how. That is exactly what I try to find out. I just read on [link](http://cutecom.sourceforge.net/), that it should be possible to do it: Features: ..... hexadecimal input and output .....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the lower right corner you can find a dropdown menu. Set it to *Hex input*. Now you can insert hex to the "Input" LineEdit. Do not use any 0x or similar.

Example:

```
Send: 0x01 0x02 0x03 0xFF 0xAF 
Write: 010203FFAF
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know the version of cutecom you work with but for me sending double digit hexadecimal numbers without the trailing 0x worked.